# Google Sheets Image() function now requires users to hit Allow Access

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

Accessing data from external parties is newly blocked by default for any spreadsheets. This change happened starting on 07/02/2024. I have many PHP scripts that creates spreadsheets and prints them in PDF programmatically but now the spreadsheets cannot access data from external parties anymore and thus the result is wrong.

I cannot find a way in the Google Sheets API documentation how to allow access programmatically.

Before day 7 all the flow was working correctly, the image URLs are public and without access restrictions, anyone has a solution to grant access programmatically?

here is some of the code where I use the IMAGE() function:

```
foreach($ORDEN["pics_docs"] as $pic)
{
    $currentRow++;
    array_push($requests_mergeCellsInRow, get_mergeCellsInRow_request($currentRow, $sc, $ct, $sheetId));
    array_push($requests_formatForCells, get_formatConceptWForRow($currentRow, $sc, $ct, $sheetId));
    array_push($requests_updateDimensionPropertiesForRow, get_updateDimensionPropertiesForRow_request($currentRow, $imgw, $sheetId));
    array_push($values_forCells_userEntered,["=IMAGE(\"".$urlImages."/".$id_orden."/".$pic["doc_name"]."\"; 1)", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]);
    $currentRow++;
    array_push($values_forCells_userEntered, []);
}
insertValuesOnCellsRange($values_forCells_userEntered, $sheetName.'!A3', $serviceSheets, $spreadsheetID, "USER_ENTERED");
batchUpdate(array_merge($requests_mergeCellsInRow, $requests_bordersForCells, $requests_formatForCells, $requests_updateDimensionPropertiesForRow), $serviceSheets, $spreadsheetID);
```

The sheet is correct except for the lock permission which breaks the flow and the only permissions I have assigned to the sheet is:

```
    $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $newPermission->setType("anyone");
    $newPermission->setRole("reader");
    $result = $serviceDrive->permissions->create($spreadsheetID, $newPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
```

I attach a couple of images with the legend of the problem

[image: Message Warning in a new spreadsheet with image() in A1 cell]

[image: Message in spreadsheets generated by script]

Comment: What do you mean by before day seven

Comment: I mean that all my flow was working correctly before February 7th, starting on the 7th with the change that Google applied it affected all my implementations.

Comment: Can you share some sample images of the issue you are encountering?

Comment: Of course, i've edited the post to show a couple of images

Comment: I have found a [forum](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/ihna0293kSY?pli=1) where they encounter the same issue that you have when using `image()` , as a workaround he used `insertCellImage()` instead. However, this function is available for Google App Script only. But I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I had already reviewed that forum but it does not solve the problem that this Google change generated, the solution must be to be able to grant the permission through the API or some call, with inspect you can see that the action of allowing the permission performs the call to: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[spreadsheetId]/externaldata/allowexternalurlaccess?token=[token]&includes_info_params=true&cros_files=false

Unfortunately, there is apparently no documentation on the internet on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently ran into the same issue, and i put together this apps script function to fix it:

```
function addExternalPartyPermission(ss_caller) {
  ss_callerId = ss_caller.getId();
  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  // adding permission by fetching this url
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss_callerId}/externaldata/allowexternalurlaccess?token=${token}&includes_info_params=true&cros_files=false`;

  const params = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
}
```

Run this as the spreadsheet owner account, and pass in the spreadsheet that you're looking to add permission for as "ss_caller", and the permissions will be added.

Comment: Hi Alex, with the script published as a web application and running it with curl from the php script the solution worked, thanks